# Launching a Bash Shell from Powerpoint

Tags: bash, microsoft-powerpoint

Does anyone know of a way to launch a Bash Shell directly from a PowerPoint presentation?

I've seen a lot of GOLANG Gophers running code from their powerpoint presentation (or at least I thought they were PowerPoint). I'm doing some training, and it would be great if I could run Live examples from my Bash Shell in the Powerpoint presentation.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it would be a macro-enabled PowerPoint document. Office macros, although generally only intended for things like automating tasks within a document or spreadsheet, are quite powerful and execute essentially without a sandbox, so they are certainly capable of doing things such as launching `bash.exe` in response to some trigger (which could be anything from just opening the file to double-clicking a particular place on a specific slide on a Thursday).

Obviously, Office documents executing arbitrary programs on your computer is a security disaster waiting to happen. In fact, macro malware is pretty common on Windows, though recent versions of Office make it a lot harder to be affected by it. By default, macros are disabled in all Office programs; you need to manually enable them for individual documents that you trust. This involves multiple clicks and some moderately-scary warning messages.